# Using terminal on mac via an executable file

Tags: macos, shell

Right so I wanted to automate a process which I have to do quite often for a program that I run quite often and sometimes open up multiple of.

Normally I open up Terminal and type in the following commands in order:

```
cd ExoClient
mono ExoClient.exe
(email)
(pass)
```

So I made an executable file for this called login.command on my mac.
I typed in this is order:

```
cd ExoClient
mono ExoClient.exe
example_email@gmail.com
example_password
```

So the first two lines work but the last two don't do anything. I thought that this could be because the top 2 commands are actual mac commands and the last two lines are just inputs. But I don't know how to make sure the inputs are inputted.

OR another reason why it might not work could be because I need to delay the inputs. I'd love to know what I can input here to make it wait a second before an input is inputted.

Thanks for reading, would appreciate any help.

Comment: The batch-file tag is for Microsoft operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

I made a similar post on mac rumours. 
The solution was to do :

```
cd ExoClient
mono ExoClient.exe email pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand about the command-line is that there's a bunch of different things in play.

The first is the commands themselves, these are typically typed in or run from a script.

The second is "standard input" or STDIN, which is where programs take keyboard input. As far as you're concerned there's no difference when using the shell, but to the shell itself there's a huge difference. That program wants input from STDIN. The shell script is being told to run *two subsequent commands*.

Instead try this:

```
cd ExoClient
echo "example_email@gmail.com\
example_password" | mono ExoClient.exe
```

The `|` character means "send output to" in rough terms, so the output of `echo` goes through to the `mono` program. Output, or STDOUT, is another thing the shell wants to deal with.

Or have a secondary file that contains those two lines and give that as "input":

```
cd ExoClient
mono ExoClient.exe < login.txt
```

Where `login.txt` has the two lines and `<` means "take input from this file".

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, I tried the first method. When I ran the shell this message came up:
https://gyazo.com/bbfd269d078d2330387b8ca875d73a20

Comment: You may need to add another blank line to `login.txt` to act as a "return" as it seems to be waiting for the end of input.

Comment: Tried method two, came up with a message saying it could not find the directory.

Comment: You'll need to specify the path to that file if it's not in the same directory as `ExoClient.exe`. The easy thing is to simply move that file into the same directory.

Comment: Tried that, thanks. It doesn't give me the response of not being able to find a directory but it gives me the same result as method 1. It doesn't enter in the email and pass.

Comment: If you have `example_email@gmail.com<newline>example_password<newline>` in your file where `<newline>` is a literal new line, then it should work as you did before, though maybe `ExoClient.exe` is just being fussy. Is there another way to specify this information than via typing it in? This question is the second result in Google for "ExoClient.exe" so I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: That's exactly what I had in my documents. And I'm using ConsoleClient but given the nature of it, gaming related, not sure if people would just straight up ignore something related to that.

Comment: If you have the source for it maybe you could make it take credentials from an INI-type file to avoid having to shovel it in over STDIN. You could try putting in a few more newlines just because, but without seeing the exact program I can't say for sure. Usually directing input from the file or typing it in manually is the same thing. One possibility is it's waiting for `<CR><LF>`, DOS-style, vs. `<LF>` POSIX-style.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But here is what it looks like when I used the code you suggested. https://gyazo.com/f3428c5bf2fc06febcbf49293f96eb44

Comment: As for the .ini file idea, this program uses a .ini file to customise settings. I'm not sure how I'd go about writing a suitable .ini file to help me though.